# SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error while fetching registration id using Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing GoogleCloudMessaging in Android.

Using the below code I am retrieving Registration ID

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);;
String registrationID = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

Sometimes I am not able to get the Registration id because I am getting `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error.

Is there a way to fix this? Here's a link to 
[GoogleCloudMessaging](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html).

Comment: Excatly the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For getting GCMRegistrationID it is mandatory to enable google play services. With out these you can't get GCMID. Before going to registration please check goole play is in active state or not.

Comment: Yes, I am checking whether Google Play Service is available or not before getting the registration id. Even then i am getting this error sometimes.